# Linq-to-Sql expression with null object throws NPE

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-expressions

The following linq-to-sql expression throws null pointer exception.

```
List<string> nameList = GetNames();
db.Users.FindSync(u => nameList.Contains(u.Name))
```

I have found the issue is that `nameList` is null. But the following update isn't helping.

```
u => nameList == null || nameList.Contains(u.Name)
```

I have found from google searches that NPE occurs during conversion to SQL (not during evaluation). Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: You could try `List<string> nameList = GetNames() ??
 Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToList()` and keep your db call the same

Comment: @DanD That could work but the query would return empty list, instead of all users. If nameLists is null, i'd like to return all user elements from db.

Comment: Can't you use simple if statement to workaround it?

Comment: if you want full list if nameList is null then even without NPE your logic is wrong, should be something like `nameList == null ? db.Users.GetAll() : db.Users.FindSync(u => u.blah blah)

Comment: @GhasanAl-Sakkaf Do you mean outside of the query? Yes, but that would create multiple linq query statements. The number of statements would grow exponentially as more filters are added. Ex: `u => nameList.Contains(u.Name) && emailList.Contains(u.Email)`

Comment: @WallSkyBlue All elements that evaluate true for the where clause will be returned. I think the expression should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have little options here. Here is one I would normally use to tackle such problems.

```
var list = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };
var list2 = new string[] { "One", "Five" };
var db = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Four" };

var conditions = new List<Func<String, bool>>();
if (list != null)
{
    conditions.Add(s => list.Contains(s));
}

if (list2 != null)
{
    conditions.Add(s => list2.Contains(s));
}

var query = db.AsEnumerable(); // AsQuerable on your side.
foreach (var condition in conditions)
{
    query = query.Where(condition);
}

var result = query.ToList(); // Outputs "One".
```

Answer (score 3):

Think of what inside `.FindSync(u => ......)` happen in another context/realm/dimension
and `Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.`

You may think that "but why nameList.Contains is working" it is because library did support conversion of that to SQL. Sadly nameList itself is not supported, also nameList == null is not supported.

Your solution should be doing null check outside/before linq
maybe something like

```
var uResult = nameList == null ? db.Users.GetAll() : db.Users.FindSync(u => nameList.Contains(u.Name))
```